# How to fetch already rotated logs in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Currently I tried to fetch already rotated logs within the node using --since-time parameter.
Can anybody suggest what is the command/mechanism to fetch already rotated logs within kubernetes architecture using commands

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Kubernetes does not store logs for you, it's just providing an API to access what's on disk. For long term storage look at things like Loki, ElasticSearch, Splunk, SumoLogic, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
We are trying to fetch the log details which are stored as max cap, Let's say the log is rotated today and the logfile of yesterday's is still available in the node.
Can't we fetch yesterday's log using any of kubernetes command with parameters?

Comment: Nope, what you see is what you get. It's a very simplistic system. As I said, set up a real log data management tool if you want more.